# getting equivalent pixel of two different wide resolutions

Tags: c++, opencv, resolutions

I want to get the equivalent pixel location of two different wide resolutions.

Here is an example.

In a 1366x768 resolution, the desired pixel is located in row 120 and column 300.
I want to convert it to a lower resolution and get the equivalent of 120x300 point from the original to the converted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use percent.

e.g. `120/1366=60/683`=`x ~ 0.0878` and `300/768=25/64`=`y ~ 0.3906`. Now simply multiply these percent with your desired resolution.

For example if you have the resolution `800x600` and want this position just multiply.

```
x = 800 * 0.0878 = 70.24
y = 600 * 0.3906 = 234.36
```

This works because the position got kindof 'normalized' so that it lays between `0` and `1`. Whatever you multiply this with will have same 'dimensions'. e.g. assume we want the position `400x300` from screen `800x600` in another screen so that it has same ratios. We can do similiar to your problem up there:

```
x = 400 / 800 = 0.5
y = 300 / 600 = 0.5
```

To get the position for any other screen we multiply the result from there with the resolution.

[Percentage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, will check it out later and see if it resulted my desired output. Anyway, do you have any reference about this that I can read?

Comment: added a brief explanation